# PHP & MySQL - what I want is not outputting

Tags: php, mysql

So I am quite new to PHP (and MySQL) and have been working on some code alongside an author of lynda.com. I am trying to get this output:[image: Output I would like]

Here is the output I get:
[image: What I am getting]

My code is here:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>

<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="subjects">
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * ";
            $query .= "FROM subjects ";
            $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
            $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
            $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            confirm_query($subject_set);
            ?>  
        <?php
            while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
        ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $subject["menu_name"]; ?>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * ";
                    $query .= "FROM pages ";
                    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
                    $query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} "; //I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE.
                    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
                    $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    confirm_query($page_set);
                ?>
                <ul class="pages">
                    <?php
                        while ($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {

                     echo $page["menu_name"];

                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php mysqli_free_result($page_set); ?>     
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
            <?php 
                mysqli_free_result($subject_set);
            ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <h2>Manage Content</h2>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

What I am trying to do is obviously get the additional pages that appear under the subjects, I have done the MySQL correctly but I am having problems with what I think is that line of code (after replacing the value from its current one to 1 but I am not sure how I could change it to make what I want outputted get outputted.

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Widget Corp</title>
        <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Widget Corp</h1>
    </div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="subjects">

                    <li>
                About Widget Corp                               <ul class="pages">

                </ul>
            </li>
                        <li>
                Products                                <ul class="pages">

                </ul>
            </li>
                        <li>
                Services                                <ul class="pages">

                </ul>
            </li>
                        <li>
                Today's Widget Trivia                               <ul class="pages">

                </ul>
            </li>
                            </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <h2>Manage Content</h2>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright 20xx, Widget Corp</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Here]

This is what I get.

[image: Here again]

Here is what I get in the console if I run it with specific values which I enter.

Comment: Include the generated HTML. Is error reporting on? Does `$page["menu_name"]` contain `html`?

Comment: please provide your database tables and relations between them.

Comment: You're not doing any error checking of your queries, which you need to do. The quotes in your query string, as evidenced by the code highlighting, are messed up and causing your query to fail.

Comment: Quotes should work fine inside the curly braces. Just tried this and it works fine: `$foo["bar"] = "baz"; echo "{$foo["bar"]}";`

Comment: Error reporting is on.

Comment: You're not doing any MySQLi error reporting, but you will find the errors in your error logs.

Comment: Echo your `Select pages` query to make sure it looks right.

Comment: `$subject['id'] = 'foo';
$query = "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} ";` I get `AND subject_id = foo` Note that there are not any quotes around `foo` which can be problematic if the is is not a number. echo `$query` after it is all assembled and show us that output.

Comment: My guess is the data isn't in the database, or not in the expected format. You should really be doing this database stuff away from the HTML. Also you're not placing your page names in `<li>` elements.

Comment: I did echo $query; after and it seems to replace the {$subject["id"]} to AND subject_id = 6. Does this mean anything?

Comment: @Bob that looks correct. Go to the Mysql command line and make sure the table is populated with the data you are trying to fetch.

Comment: I will add the information from the menu_name in pages in my answer.

Comment: I think I have everything.

Comment: Update: Nothing run from inside the loop in the loop and if I take out $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 "; and $query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject["id"]} "; then it runs but all values from subject_id load in the same sections.

Comment: @Bob In a previous comment you said `$subject['id']` is evaluating to 6. It doesn't look like you have that ID in your pages. Maybe the IDs got out of sync somehow. This will happen if you had to drop and reinsert data

Comment: Please give me some indication on how to fix this, as I said, I am quite new to this. :)

Comment: How could I reset it for it to work, anything. If you know could you please answer in depth as I have to go. Thanks for replying. I think that may fix the problem. I did drop data out when I was doing the subjects table before I knew I could edit visibility (so I ended up deleting a bunch of them and remaking them) and the id values are all messed up. Could this be part of the problem, do you think I could remake my database but with id values which made more sense again and then tell PHP to grab the stuff from that database instead?

Comment: It worked, thank you all so much!